# SQL Find All user that have two history in a certain order

Tags: mysql, sql, request

I'm looking for a SQL request that I can't find in internet (and I didn't found a solution myself).

I have two different table user and history and a table user_history that link the two tables.

For example :

---

### USER

```
    id name 
    1 John
    2 Edie
    3 France
    4 Gabriel
```

5 Ellen

---

### History

```
    id date_entered type
    1 2017-07-01 36
    2 2017-07-02 52
    3 2017-07-03 25
    4 2017-07-04 69
    5 2017-07-05 85
    6 2017-07-06 74
    7 2017-07-07 45
    8 2017-07-08 85
    9 2017-07-09 25
    10 2017-07-10 78
```

---

### USER_HISTORY

```
    id id_user id_history
    1  1  1
    2  1  2
    3  1  3
    4  1  4
    5  2  5
    6  2  6
    7  1  7
    8  1  8
    9  2  9
    10 1  10
```

In this example, all history are made by user 1 and 2 (user 2 have history 5,6 and 9).

So the question is :

What is the SQL request that get me all the users that have in their history an history type 25 and then some days LATER an history type 85 ?

In this example, only user 1 (John) is ok because he has a history type 25 on 2017-07-03 and then an history type 85 on 2017-07-08.
User 2 (Edie) is not ok because even if he has an history 25 and 85, the first one was 85 and the 25.

Is that clear ? 
Can you help me please ?

Comment: What have you tried? People will not write code for you on this site. They will help you fix your current code. Check out https://sqlzoo.net/

Comment: Note that the id column in your user_history table is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` twice with `HISTORY` table, e.g.:

```
SELECT h1.id_user 
FROM (
SELECT u.id_user, h.date_entered
FROM user_history u
JOIN history h ON u.id_history = h.id
WHERE h.type = 25) h1
JOIN (
  SELECT u.id_user, h.date_entered
  FROM user_history u
  JOIN history h ON u.id_history = h.id
  WHERE h.type = 85
  ) h2 ON h1.id_user = h2.id_user
WHERE h1.date_entered < h2.date_entered;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77994a/13/0)**.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer but I think it has a mistake because I het 0 results. (I think the "WHERE h1.type = 25 AND h2.type = 85" condition is wrong because the request with only "WHERE h1.type = 25" or "h2.type = 85" get me results but with these two conditions -> 0).

Comment: As `h1` and `h2` are two different tables, `h1.type = 25 AND h2.type = 85` should give you the results. Can you try with `h1.type = 25` alone and add `h2.type` in `SELECT` to see which values it returns back?

Comment: Yes, I agree, it should work but it doesn't and I don't understand neither.I tried your test and I get h2.type = 25

Comment: @user3082863 updated the answer with the working SQL Fiddle.